# Show that there are k directed walks from a to b in gamma having no common directed edge pairwise

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, directed-graphs

Let $\Gamma$ be a digraph, $k$ a natural number and $a$, $b$ vertices in $\Gamma$ such that $$ \operatorname{outdegree}(a)-\operatorname{indegree}(a)=\operatorname{indegree}(b)-\operatorname{outdegree}(b)=k >0$$  and $$\operatorname{outdegree}(v)=\operatorname{indegree}(v)$$ for all other vertices in $\Gamma$ exept $a$ and $b$.

Show that there are $k$ directed walks from $a$ to $b$ in $\Gamma$ having no common directed edge pairwise.

I dont really know how to do this, but I was thinking if i could take some subgraph that is Euler graph and use that but im not sure if thats allowed or if there is any more simpler way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is naturally to assume that the graph $\Gamma$ is finite. Start walk from $a$, not going along each edge twice. Since the graph $\Gamma$ is finite, we shall stick at some step. Since $\operatorname{outdegree}(v)=\operatorname{indegree}(v)$ for all vertices in $\Gamma$ except $a$ and $b$, we can stick only at the vertex $b$. So we went a walk from $a$ to $b$. It is easy to see that this walk contains a subwalk starting from $a$ and ending at $b$ without other occurrences of $a$ and $b$. 
Removing this subwalk from $\Gamma$, we see that the residual graph satisfies all the conditions stated for $\Gamma$, but with $k=k-1$ instead of $k$. So we can proceed the same way until we shall find $k$ pairwise edge-disjoint directed walks from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: But could the graph be disconnected after we remove the subwalk?

Comment: @mathnoob At the first glance this seems to be a problem. But the conditions imposed on vertex degrees assure that we can stick only at the vertex $b$. In particular, $b$ is always accessible from $a$.